# Event Handler stopped working in current release of Window 10

Tags: vb.net, event-handling, windows-10

I have an event handler that monitors feedback from Canon Camera.  Had no issue with it in earlier versions of Windows10 but one of my clients updated yesterday and it stopped working.

```
  Public Shared Function handleObjectEvent( _
                ByVal inEvent As Integer, _
                ByVal inRef As IntPtr, _
                ByVal inContext As IntPtr, _
                ByVal camera As IntPtr)
         As Long

    Dim rtn As Long

    Select Case inEvent

        Case kEdsObjectEvent_DirItemRequestTransfer

            If globals.isCamera1 Then
                Form1.controller1.actionPerformed("download", inRef)
            Else
                Form1.controller2.actionPerformed("download", inRef)
            End If

        Case Else
            '//Release unnecessary objects.
            If IsNothing(inRef) = False Then
                EdsRelease(inRef)
            End If

    End Select

    rtn = CLng(EDS_ERR_OK)
    Return rtn

End Function
```

Comment: What happens now it's "stopped working"? what have you tried?

Comment: @Matt Lacey     I started by putting in flags to identify that it was the above event handler that wasn't receiving the "item request transfer" message from the camera.  I have been searching to see if Microsoft has recently changed how it handles threading.

Comment: @MattLacey We have used this code with no issues since XPsp1. It is working worked on boxes upgraded to W10 about 4 months ago. It just doesn't work now on any box that is upgraded to W10 recently.  I have a hunch that the Camera doesn't have permission to create a thread back to the PC, only receive.  We can send commands to the camera and request information, the camera just can't seem to send us notices.

Answer (score 0):

Okay for those folks out there using Canon SDK, ver 2.14; it works with Windows 10(as in 10.0.0.10240) but not Windows 10(1511)(as in 10.0.10586).  You will need to update to Canon SDK ver 3.2.  Best of Luck.